# My moto x wont turn on or charge

Tags: moto-x

So my Motorola X will not turn on or charge. Some other people have told me to connect it to a 5 volts 2.1 amps charger but that wont work for me. If any of you know a way that can work for me I would love it.

Comment: What caused it to not turn on or charge?

Comment: Well that's what I don't know but I guess it would be helpful to know that it was on and was at around 40-50 % charge then just shut down and wouldn't turn on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure you're using a known good charger, It's possible your phone just needs a reset. Try holding first the volume down button, and then the power switch at the same time for several seconds. If that doesn't work, try volume up and then the power button for several seconds. A few devices require all three be pressed at once. Do this after the charger has been connected for at least a half hour leaving it connected while you try the button combinations.

If that doesn't work, and you're certain you're using a known good charger and/or cable that work on other devices, your phone is very likely dead. It could be the battery or another hardware problem.

And, for future reference, it's very hard on LiIon batteries to run them completely dead and especially to leave them that way for very long. Phones will shut themselves down when the battery is too low but they continue to draw a small amount of power even while off. And that small drain can eventually destroy the battery.

Comment: In other words, don't let devices sit around dead.

Comment: I just want to say, my daughters phone died and wouldnt turn on. Had it in my charger for an hour. I did the power and down button like suggested and its rebooting. Says battery low which I know in her case means dead. Charging now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues.  Check out https://support.sprint.com/support/article/Troubleshoot-when-your-Moto-X-Pure-Edition-doesnt-turn-on/WTroubleshootingGuide_542_GKB89625-dvc9560007prd

For me, all I had to do was hold the power button for 30 seconds and boom, phone is on now. :D

Answer (score 0):

tried everything plugged in laptop charge port and is no charging. before it wouldn't charge power up or restart just come on long enough to tell me that it was at 0% charge. charging fine now. Try laptop port to charge first may save a lot of time, up to 20% charge in 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

My Moto X Play died completely after I plugged it in to my camera charger when the normal charger went walkabout. Retrospectively, I found it had charged up to 100 % and hibernated to protective mode to avoid damaging the battery. After lots of Googling I held the Volume Down and Power On Buttons until lots of gobbledook appeared on the screen about initiating a hard re-start or whatever and everything has worked fine since.

Answer (score 0):

*phone stopped responding properly so I turned it off and it wouldn't turn back on when I tried, even plugged up and holding volume button..*
**Solution:**
Held power down for 10-30 seconds after leaving phone charging for over an hour and now it's restarted at 100%.
Moto X 2nd gen

Answer (score 0):

Moto X Style:
Costed me 60 seconds (stopwatch check) before I got into the bootmenu again, by holding Power and volume up button. Old phone but still happy with it, live another day!!!